# Loop not clearing previous array variables?

Tags: php, loops, preg-match-all

For some reason when running my script, if nothing should be returned for $addr it just uses the previous result which is not correct. I need it to simply insert in the database blank. Here is an example of whats happening

```
Insert 12345678
inserted wo 12345678

Insert 12222222
Insert 123 test st
inserted wo 12222222
inserted addr 123 test st

Insert 44444444
inserted wo 44444444
inserted addr 123 test st

Insert 555555555
inserted wo 555555555
inserted addr 123 test st
```

Below is my code:

```
$handle = fopen("./dumps/omega.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        // process the line read.
        echo $line;
        echo "<br>";

// Getting Address
    $ptn2 = "/\d+[ ](?:[A-Za-z0-9-]+[ ]?)+/";
    preg_match_all($ptn2, $line, $matches2, PREG_SET_ORDER);

// Getting WO
    $ptn = "/[0-9]{8}/";
    preg_match_all($ptn, $line, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);


// Printing
    //Address
    foreach($matches2 as $match2) { echo "Addr: " . $match2[0];
        echo "<br>"; }
        // WO
        foreach($matches as $match) { echo "WO: " . $match[0];
        echo "<br>"; }
        echo "<br>";
        echo "<hr>";

// Checking Import Status

    $wo = $match[0];
    $addr = $match2[0];

    $checkwo = "SELECT * FROM completed WHERE wo = '" .mysql_real_escape_string($wo). "'";
    $checkwo = mysql_query($checkwo) or die(mysql_error());

if(mysql_num_rows($checkwo) == 0) {
     // row not found, do stuff...
     echo "<b>IMPORTING!</b>";
     echo "<br>";
     echo $wo;
     echo "<br>";
     echo $addr;
     echo "<br>";

     //SQL Import
     $sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO completed (wo, addr) VALUES ('".$wo."', '".$addr."')";
     //mysql_query($sqlinsert) or die(mysql_error());


} else {
    // do other stuff...
    echo "Already exists...";

}
        echo "<br>";
        echo "<hr>";
        echo "<hr>";

    }

    fclose($handle);
} else {
    // error opening the file.
    echo "error";
}
```

I have corrected this by adding the following inside my loop

```
unset( $match[0] );
unset( $match2[0] );
```

Comment: well you caould start by switching to PDO or at the very least, use mysql_real_escape_string

Comment: PDO or `mysqli_*` should replace your standard `mysql_` functions - this is inheritly insecure code.

Comment: Thanks I will look into it